# SQL: Subtracting 1 day from a timestamp date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, casting, timestamp

I am using Datagrip for Postgresql.  I have a table with a date field in timestamp format `(ex: 2016-11-01 00:00:00)`.  I want to be able to:

1. apply a mathematical operator to subtract 1 day
2. filter it based on a time window of today-130 days
3. display it without the hh/mm/ss part of the stamp (2016-10-31)

Current starting query:

```
select org_id, count(accounts) as count, ((date_at) - 1) as dateat 
from sourcetable 
where  date_at <= now() - 130
group by org_id, dateat
```

The `((date_at)-1)` clause on line 1 results in:

> [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone -
>   integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
>   You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 69

The `now()` clause spawns a similar message:

> [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone -
>   integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
>   You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: ...

Online guides to type casts are singularly unhelpful. Input is appreciated.

Answer (score 517, accepted):

Use the `INTERVAL` type to it. E.g:

```
--yesterday
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY';

--Unrelated: PostgreSQL also supports some interesting shortcuts:
SELECT 
    'yesterday'::TIMESTAMP, 
    'tomorrow'::TIMESTAMP, 
    'allballs'::TIME AS aka_midnight;
```

You can do the following then:

```
SELECT 
    org_id,
    count(accounts) AS COUNT,
    ((date_at) - INTERVAL '1 DAY') AS dateat
FROM 
    sourcetable
WHERE 
    date_at <= now() - INTERVAL '130 DAYS'
GROUP BY 
    org_id,
    dateat;
```

### TIPS

#### Tip 1

You can append multiple operands. *E.g.: how to get last day of current month?*

```
SELECT date_trunc('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 DAY';
```

#### Tip 2

You can also create an interval using `make_interval` function, useful when you need to create it at runtime (not using literals):

```
SELECT make_interval(days => 10 + 2);
SELECT make_interval(days => 1, hours => 2);
SELECT make_interval(0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0.0);
```

### More info:

[Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

[datatype-datetime (Especial values)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#id-1.5.7.13.19.8).

Comment: For those who were wondering, "allballs" is a literal for midnight, because it looks like 00:00:00.

Comment: Another tip: If you have stored the days in a db column (lets say num_of_days), you can use `SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY' * num_of_days`;

Answer (score 22):

You can cast a `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE`, which allows you to subtract an `INTEGER` from it.

For instance, to get yesterday:

```sql
now()::DATE - 1
```

So your query will become:

```sql
SELECT org_id, date_at::DATE - 1 AS dateat, COUNT(accounts) AS count
FROM sourcetable 
WHERE date_at <= NOW()::DATE - 130
GROUP BY 1, 2
```