# How to subtract a number of days in one column from CURRENT_DATE in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a column called `number_of_days_since_event` and I want to change it to `data_of_last_event`, the way I can do that is subtracting today's date from the number of days in the `number_of_days_since_event` column. But I do not know how to subtract days in a column.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079791/subtracting-1-day-from-a-timestamp-date#_=_) answers the problem when you know the number of days in advance, i.e., if I would like to subtract 10 days from today it would be:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10 days';
```

However, I would like to do something like:

```sql
SELECT  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL  "myTable.number_of_days_since_event" 'days'
FROM myTable;
```

But this does not work leading to the error message: `syntax error at or near "'day'"`

Answer (score 1):

The following using `concat` solves my problem:

```
SELECT  CURRENT_DATE - concat(myTable.number_of_days_since_event::text,' day')::interval
FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with a `date` result, you could use

```
SELECT current_date - number_of_days_since_event::integer
FROM mytable;
```