# How to get records from last 24h in HQL?

Tags: java, hql

I want to get all records in last 24h in [HQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28framework%29#Hibernate_Query_Language_(HQL)).

In sql I know that I can get like this:

```
select * from acc where created BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '24 HOURS' AND NOW()
```

But in HQL, `INTERVAL` is not supported. Any suggestion how can I achieve this?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080928/14756421

Comment: Please take more care in your typing and spelling. This site is meant to be a formal knowledge base, more like Wikipedia, less like a casual chat room. I did some editing for you this time.